# Store information in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to store information with the webstorage API. I created a class but the console returns the message "undefined". I was expecting the console to return 20 and 60. Can you help me identify my mistake? Thank you :)

```
class Timer {
    constructor(minutes, secondes){
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.secondes = secondes;
        this.minutesEltHtml = document.getElementById("minutes");
        this.secondesEltHtml = document.getElementById("secondes");
    }

    setMinutesSecondes(){
        sessionStorage.setItem("minutes", this.minutes);
        sessionStorage.setItem("secondes", this.secondes);
    }

    getMinutesSecondes(){
        return sessionStorage.getItem("minutes");
        return sessionStorage.getItem("secondes");
    }

    display(){
        console.log(timer.getMinutesSecondes());
        //console.log(timer.this.minutes);
    }
}

let timer = new Timer(20, 60);
timer.display();
```

Line 20: undefined

Comment: Your code is missing `this.minutes = minuntes;`

Comment: You never actually store it in the session storage?

Comment: Please post all of your code, and, this is JS - stop using classes. It will hurt you later.

Comment: The function setMinutesSecondes() is never called. Call this function in the constructor.

Comment: @Willtheoct Why were they added if they shouldn't be used?

Comment: Also, you can't write two return in the same function one after the other.

Comment: @Willtheoct, while I personally agree with you, that is quite an opinionated statement and probably shouldn't be simply stated as if it was fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You don't set the storage as you are not calling the method that does it. either call `timer.setMinutesSecondes()` before calling display or do so in the constructor as per my example below.

2: It's seconds not secondes (sorry for the pedantry).

3: Your `getMinutesSecondes` function has 2 return calls. Execution will stop after the first call. see my example below.

4: Some of the mistakes here indicate you would benefit from some introduction to JavaScript courses. Have a quick google, there is a wealth of free content online.

```
class Timer {
    constructor(minutes, secondes){
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.secondes = secondes;
        this.minutesEltHtml = document.getElementById("minutes"); 
        this.secondesEltHtml = document.getElementById("secondes"); 
        this.setMinutesSecondes();
    }

    setMinutesSecondes(){
        sessionStorage.setItem("minutes", this.minutes);
        sessionStorage.setItem("secondes", this.secondes);
    }

    getMinutesSecondes(){
        return { // you were calling return twice... only the first line would have returned
            mintues: sessionStorage.getItem("minutes"), 
            secondes: sessionStorage.getItem("secondes")
        };
    }

    display(){
        console.log(this.getMinutesSecondes());
    }
}

let timer = new Timer(20, 60);
timer.display(); // output {minutes:20, secondes:60}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting `undefined` as the return value of `sessionStorage.getItem` is because the value you are trying to retrieve from the storage has not be set on that storage. You defined a method to store the data to the storage without calling that method ( `setMinutesSecondes` ).
Do this instead ( Assuming the code you presented is your complete code )

```
class Timer {
    constructor(minutes, secondes){
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.secondes = secondes;
        this.minutesEltHtml = document.getElementById("minutes");
        this.secondesEltHtml = document.getElementById("secondes");
    }

    setMinutesSecondes(){
        sessionStorage.setItem("minutes", this.minutes);
        sessionStorage.setItem("secondes", this.secondes);
    }

    getMinutesSecondes(){
        return {
           minutes: sessionStorage.getItem("minutes"),
           secondes: sessionStorage.getItem("secondes");
        };
    }

    display(){
        console.log(timer.getMinutesSecondes());
        //console.log(timer.this.minutes);
    }
}

let timer = new Timer(20, 60);
timer.setMinutesSecondes(); // if you don't wish to call this method here, you can still call this method in the constructor function 
timer.display();
```